# How to make all elements in a node list disappear except target element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/m4rsibar/pen/zyPBoz?editors=0110

I've made a codepen example of the effect I'm going for (I've included the code that creates the effect at the very top of the css section), except I want to do it in javascript. (unless there's a way to fix the issues I'm having with the css version)

The issue: the hover is on the div containing the circular elements, if you hover in the div, and aren't on top of an element they all go out of view.

I'm using the :not selector in css to achieve this and to put it on the parent element is the only way I know how to get this to work, I've tried playing around and changing stuff up, to no avail, so I decided to do this with javascript.

In another codepen I tried to simplify as much as possible to try to achieve the effect I'm going for. I've only gotten thus far:
https://codepen.io/m4rsibar/pen/yGPqZM

as you can see when you leave the box it doesn't go back to the original opacity.

Should I be using classes and toggling them?

```
let lis= document.querySelectorAll('li')
console.log(lis)

lis.forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    lis.forEach(function(li) {

       e.target.style.opacity="1";
      if(e.target.style.opacity==="1"){
  li.style.opacity="0.3";
         }else{
             li.style.opacity="1";
         } 
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simpler approach using only a line of `CSS` and no `JavaScript`. Because `opacity: 1` is implicit, we don't have to declare that at all, only styles for the non-hovered state.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

After your feedback and [latest example](https://codepen.io/m4rsibar/pen/aPVQaq), I took another stab at it. My goal was avoid the double `active` class on both the `ul` and active `li`. It's not ideal from a performance standpoint, but beyond that, it's more `JavaScript` and `CSS` to maintain.

What I came up with is a function that detects if an `li` is the current target (while the mouse is somewhere inside the `ul`). If the current target is *not* an `li` it means that our `ul` is active but no children are being hovered. I toggle a class accordingly. I like that everything is stored in the `ul` and we no longer need any `li` event tracking.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

function boxEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add('active');
}

function boxLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('active');
}

function boxMove(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('childrenInactive', e.target.tagName !== 'LI');
}

ul.addEventListener('mousemove', boxMove);
ul.addEventListener('mouseenter', boxEnter);
ul.addEventListener('mouseleave', boxLeave);
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/200x200');
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  cursor: crosshair;
  will-change: filter, transform;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul.active li {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

ul li:hover,
ul.active.childrenInactive li {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3reaqsw/

Comment: Did you see the first codepen? I was just using the second link to try to simplify, in my mind, what was going on.  The logic you provided helped with the second link but ultimately the first link is where the real problem lies.    With the logic you provided the initial state of the images is low opacity, and that's not ideal

Comment: @m4rsib4r I will take another look at it.

Comment: you rock, this has stumped me for much too long now... a second set of eyes is very appreciated.

Comment: @m4rsib4r I liked what you did and took it a little further. Let me know if this works for you.